# how to confirm or delete rows in a website in php without showing id or name or anything in the value of the input or button of confirm or delete?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a page to get all rows from table in a database and make every row comes with a button to confirm or delete that row by putting the id of row in the value of button and that works well
but 
what if someone pressed a right click on the button of delete or confirm and then chose inspect element and (from browser console ) edit the value of button which is **' id of row '** and make a delete or confirm .. it will delete or confirm another row that i don't wanna delete or confirm.
For example:
if i edit (from browser console ) the value of the delete button in the row one where id =1 and change it to 3 and press delete button,
row 3 will be deleted however i pressed delete on row 1....how can i prevent that from happening??
here is the code after connecting on the db

`$show_temp=mysql_query("select id,pat_name from temp");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($show_temp))
    {
    $p_temp_name=$row['pat_name'];
    $p_temp_id=$row['id'];
    $p_temp_name=htmlspecialchars($row['pat_name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $p_temp_id=htmlspecialchars($row['id'],ENT_QUOTES);
    echo'<form method="post">';
    echo'
    <tr>
    <td>'.$p_temp_name.'</td>
    <td>
    <button type="submit" value="'.$p_temp_id.'"name="confirm">confirm </button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button type="submit" value="'.$p_temp_id.'" name="delete"> delete </button>
    </td>
    </tr>';
    echo'</form>'
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hash-tokens instead of ID_of_row to secure your parameters and after that don`t worry about inspect element values .

And you should make a conditions to check if this parameter(id or token) in your table or not , if the result is "TRUE" so you have to check that is he has a permission to delete or make any action on this row.